# Ubuntu 13.10 crashing on MacMini2013

Tags: 13.10, kernel, mac-mini

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64 on my MacMini and it worked great (graphic performance was way better than under OSX).

After upgrading to 13.10, I have on average, one crash per day. The syslog entries are all over the place, from applications accessing invalid memory to cpu core code segfaulting.
It ranges from applications freezing to the XServer restarting to a total system freeze.
Hardware does not seem to be the problem, since the machine runs fine on OSX.

I tried using a newer kernel (3.12) but still the same issues. Booting 3.8 results in a frozen system when lightdm starts.

Is there any way to analyze this further? I currently don't know where to begin.

Comment: Almost sounds like you got something corrupted during the upgrade, though I wouldn't know.

Comment: What should that be? It seems to be so deep down, that it only could be the kernel, and I already tried different ones.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Apple hardware tends to not work so great with Ubuntu for some reason. I have ran Ubuntu on Macbooks and they have always had problems. I just stick to Virtualizing Ubuntu on Mac OSX.

One thing that might help is doing a fresh install and trying to just stick to the ubuntu-tested software. Don't install any proprietary drivers or anything, just stick to the ubuntu-tested drivers and all of that stuff. Don't try to install the latest kernel or any of that. If that works well, then you can start installing drivers until you figure out which drivers are screwing it up.